# Salvar arquivo com data e hora no nome com Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Amigos, sou novo em python e estou tentando salvar um arquivo que contenha a data e a hora como nome do arquivo.

Esse é o meu código, mas não está dando certo.

Onde estou errando?

```py
from datetime import date, datetime

data = datetime.today()
hoje = data.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
nome = 'Consolidado.xlsx'

...

df.to_excel(f'{hoje}-{nome}', index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando a barra ("`/`") no nome do arquivo e se estiver usando Linux, macOS ou algum derivado de UNIX a tua data será considerada como parte do caminho do arquivo e não o seu nome. E no NTFS do Windows a barra é um caractere inválido para compor nomes de arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Substitua `/` por outro caractere, por exemplo `-`.

Isso é necessário porque o uma barra significa o caminho relativo ou absoluto do arquivo.

Comment: Muito bom Giovanni. Uma coisa tão simples. Muito obrigado.